# php preg_replace except

Tags: php, preg-replace

There are many paragraph in one test.

```
<div class="text">...</div>
<div class="content">...</div>
<div class="aa bb">...</div>
<div class="aa cc">...</div>
<div class="aa dd">...</div>
<div class="aa ee">...</div>
<div class="aa ff">...</div>
...// more type of class="aa .*"
```

I want remove all the `div class="aa"` but except `div class="aa dd"`, how to do this job? Thanks.

```
$html = preg_replace('/<div(.*?)class="aa(.*?)">([\s\S]*?)<\/div>/', '', $html);
// this will remove all the div include class 'aa', but I need remain class 'aa dd'
```

Comment: I woudl say : don't use regex to manipulate HTML. Instead, use a DOM parser, like the DOMDocument class, and its loadHTML() method.

Comment: @Pascal MARTIN, So, if there have a long long text, how to use dom parse make a require which I need? I only know use dom, get one tag name from a text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
echo preg_replace('~<div class="aa (?!dd).+?">.+?</div>~', "", $html);
```